# How to convert x versus v graph to v versus t

Tags: derivatives

Suppose that I have a V (speed) vs X (distance) graph as follows : 
[image]

I want to draw V (speed) vs t (time) graph.

[image]

But I don't wat to get the graph, I want to get the proper way of transforming graphs. How can I transform **V vs X** to **V vs t**?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let the equation of $v$ vs $x$ graph be $v=ax+b$

Then $$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=ax+b$$

$$\dfrac{dx}{ax+b}=dt$$

Integrate both sides

$$\int \dfrac{dx}{ax+b}=\int dt$$

$$\dfrac{1}{a}\ln(ax+b) = ct$$

you probably know $a$ and $b$ from the graph, find $c$ from initial condition [should be given]

Comment: Isn't the first equation for V vs t? I have V vs x.

Comment: fixed. thanks for pointing out

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am sorry for asking this but it's been almost 20 years since I've been graduated from college and it seems I've forgotten everything about Calculus, how do wet get from the second operation to third, which corresponds to "Solve this to get". Can you please explain it in baby steps?

Comment: I added an update

Comment: Thank you very much for the update. Excuse me for further questions, but when integrating we do integrate left side according to x, but right side according to t. Isn't it a bit wrong? Shouldn't we be taking the same integral on both sides; acodring to x or according to t?

Comment: @user3021830 It is called seperation of variables, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables#Ordinary_differential_equations_.28ODE.29).

Comment: That was very enlightening. Thank you very much for your help.